# Want my for loop to return letters instead of numbers in R

Tags: r, for-loop, variable-assignment, assign

```
for(k in seq(0,length(Gs@left)-nl,len=30))
{
fcs <- abs(fft(Gs@left[(k+1):(k+nl)]))
tmp <- lsfit(X,fcs,inter=F)
print(order(-tmp$coef)[1])
}
```

I have a for loop that returns a list of numbers:

```
[1] 3
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 2
```

These numbers correspond to notes on a piano and it would be a lot more useful for it to return G4 instead of 1, A4 instead of 2 etc...

Is there a way of coding my for loop to return this (ie 1 = "G4" etc...)?

I have tried assign(paste("G4"), 1) and this doesn't work.

Thank you

Comment: if you have list of integers to piano notes, you could just use match after getting order

Comment: If you post a sample of data that runs with your code, we can more easily provide code that solves your problem. Paste into your questions the output of `dput(mydata)` (where `mydata` is whatever data sample you want to provide).

Comment: Another option is to use a `list`. `x <- list(G4 = 1, A4 = 2)` and then you can use `which` to return the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set up a string that has the notes in the order implied by you musical conventions (which I am not able to intuit being entirely amusical, and seeing that @user295691 may actually understand the mathematical underpinning) . Since you only give two notes:

```
# Above the loop
notes=c("G4", "A4", "B4")   # not sure if third one is sensible musically
                            # would have guessed that A5 was next to G4
# in the loop
print( notes[ order(-tmp$coef)[1] ] )
```

Comment: Thank you, it depends which country the music is from I think. But where I am it goes from C to C, so C4, D4, E4, F4, G4, A4, B4, C5 etc...
This works well, thank you

Comment: This might be useful then: `paste0( rep( LETTERS[c(3:8,1:2)], 5), rep(1:5, each=8) )`

Answer (score 3):

Not exact answer because of lack of required info in question, but this should give you some hint

```
df<-data.frame(id=1:10, note=LETTERS[1:10], stringsAsFactors = F)

for (i in 1:5){
  x=sample(1:10,1)
  #print(x)
  print(df[match(x,df$id),2])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Writing a function to do the translation probably makes the most sense.

```
strfnote <- function(notes, base_octave=4) {
  paste0(LETTERS[(notes %% 7) + 1], trunc(notes / 7) + base_octave)
}
```

Which would give us

```
> strfnote(0:10)
 [1] "A4" "B4" "C4" "D4" "E4" "F4" "G4" "A5" "B5" "C5" "D5"
```

You could make the `strfnote` more complete, handling things like accidentals, and specifying exactly what note corresponds to "0" to set the offset.  But after some basic processing, your code can produce numbers, and then for rendering you can just pass them to this function to  get a readable form.

Answer (score 0):

Try using factors instead:

Example:

```
data <- c(1,2,3,4,5, 1,3,4)
labeled_data <- factor(data, labels = c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5"))
labeled_data
```

would return

```
[1] a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a1 a3 a4
Levels: a1 a2 a3 a4 a5
```

Comment: Thank you, the fact that it returns the Levels line is really annoying and gets in the way though.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a list pianoNotes and access the items by index [[i]].

For your example this would be:

```
pianoNotes <- list("1" = "G4") # and more
for(k in seq(0,length(Gs@left)-nl,len=30))
{
  fcs <- abs(fft(Gs@left[(k+1):(k+nl)]))
  tmp <- lsfit(X,fcs,inter=F)
  print(pianoNotes[[order(-tmp$coef)[1]]])
}
```